# Cisco RV320 in router mode loses internet connectivity?

Tags: networking, router

Cisco RV320 can work in either "Gateway" or "Router" mode.
Manual says the following about the "Router" mode

> Choose this mode if the device is on a network with other routers
>   and another device is the network gateway to the Internet or this network is
>   not connected to the Internet. In Router mode, Internet connectivity is
>   available to the network devices only if you have another router that
>   functions as the Gateway. Since firewall protection is provided by the
>   gateway, disable this device firewall.

I connect WAN port of RV320 to LAN port of a cable modem. The modem works as gateway and router on 192.168.0.0. RV320 is on 192.168.1.0 and it shows that it got 192.168.0.13 from the modem. Modem does not show that address among connected devices however.

RV320 cannot ping any internet address while modem can. Any computer connected to RV320 gets valid IP and windows even shows that network has internet connection, but there actually isn't any. For some reason RV320 manages to resolve DNS names, however.

I tried disabling firewall, Ipv6 etc to no avail.

Am I missing something?
Is RV320 not able to work use another router with NAT as gateway?
What is "Router" mode for?

Answer (score 0):

Since simply turning router in "Gateway" mode instantly fixes internet connectivity,

> on a network with other routers and another device is the network gateway to the Internet

probably means that there is gateway on the router subnet.
In my scenario the modem is on a different subnet, so RV320 must be set to Gateway mode. It's still strange that RV320 itself cannot ping internet addresses as it knows where WAN can be reached. Again, probably it looks for gateway on its own subnet.

Answer (score 0):

In this [cisco url](http://sbkb.cisco.com/CiscoSB/ukp.aspx?vw=1&docid=e3ab11fbd8a548a9b658c734062ada17_Advanced_Routing_Configuration_on_RV320_Routers.xml&pid=2&respid=0&snid=9&dispid=0&cpage=search), explain how to configure in gateway and router mode in cisco RV320

Basic:

1. The external cable (ISP) must be connected to the Internet WAN port and cable to your local network must be connected to any of the LAN ports (1,2,3,4)
2. Enter Cisco RV320 (192.168.1.1). (Change default credentials)
3. Enter "DHCP Setup" and select "Device IP Address" (default 192.168.1.1). Active "DHCP Server" and determine the range: "Range Start (Example 192.168.1.100)" and "Range End" (example 192.168.1.200) (note: don't use 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.255 into the range) and set "DNS Server/Use DNS as Bellow and set manually your DNS (example 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4) and save the changes. Finally check "DHCP Status" ip leases your local network.
4. Enter a "system management" and select "Load Balance" (Auto Mode)
5. Enter "Setup/Network" and select "IPv4 Only" and "WAN Setting Table" should be "WAN1 (and WAN2) Obtain an IP automatically"
6. In "Setup / Advanced Routing" select "Gateway"

Note: Don't use "Router" because need to set routing table and RIP.

7. Check "System Summary" that all information is correct

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.